# Pearson's r in Julia

Tags: julia

I couldn't find an already made function in Julia to compute Pearson's r so I resorted to trying to make it myself however I run into trouble.

code:

```
r(x,y) = (sum(x*y) - (sum(x)*sum(y))/length(x))/sqrt((sum(x^2)-(sum(x)^2)/length(x))*(sum(y^2)-(sum(y)^2)/length(x)))
```

if I attempt to run this on two arrays:

```
b = [4,8,12,16,20,24,28]
q = [5,10,15,20,25,30,35]
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: `*` has no method matching *(::Array{Int64,1}, ::Array{Int64,1})
in r at none:1
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pearson's r is available in Julia as [`cor`](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/stdlib/math/#Base.cor):

```
julia> cor(b,q)
1.0
```

When you're looking for functions in Julia, the [`apropos`](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/stdlib/base/?highlight=apropos#Base.apropos) function can be very helpful:

```
julia> apropos("pearson")
Base.cov(v1[, v2][, vardim=1, corrected=true, mean=nothing])
Base.cor(v1[, v2][, vardim=1, mean=nothing])
```

---

The issue you're running into with your definition is the difference between elementwise multiplication/exponentiation and matrix multiplication/exponentiation.  In order to use elementwise behavior as you intend, you need to `.*` and `.^`:

```
r(x,y) = (sum(x.*y) - (sum(x)*sum(y))/length(x))/sqrt((sum(x.^2)-(sum(x)^2)/length(x))*(sum(y.^2)-(sum(y)^2)/length(x)))
```

With only those three changes, your `r` definition seems to match Julia's `cor` to within a few ULPs:

```
julia> cor(b,q)
1.0

julia> x,y = randn(10),randn(10)
([-0.2384626335813905,0.0793838075714518,2.395918475924737,-1.6271954454542266,-0.7001484742860653,-0.33511064476423336,-1.5419149314518956,-0.8284664940238087,-0.6136547926069563,-0.1723749334766532],[0.08581770755520171,2.208288163473674,-0.5603452667737798,-3.0599443201343854,0.585509815026569,0.3876891298047877,-0.8368409374755644,1.672421071281691,0.19652240951291933,0.9838306761261647])

julia> r(x,y)
0.23514468093214283

julia> cor(x,y)
0.23514468093214275
```

Julia's [`cor` is defined iteratively](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/45f9cc5010ef1d79c57c84b12d18f571ddad13c1/base/statistics.jl#L372-L390) (this is the zero-mean implementation — calling `cor` first subtracts the mean and then calls `corzm`) which means fewer allocations and better performance.  I can't speak to the numerical accuracy.

Answer (score 3):

Your function is trying to multiply two column vectors. You will need to <s>invert</s> transpose one of them. Consider:

```
> [1,2]*[3,4]
ERROR: `*` has no method matching *(::Array{Int64,1}, ::Array{Int64,1})
```

but:

```
> [1,2]'*[3,4]
1-element Array(Int64,1)
  11
```

and:

```
> [1,2]*[3,4]'
2x2 Array(Int64,2):
  3   4
  6   8
```

Comment: Let me also add that the same problem arises when squaring vectors. `sum(x^2)` should probably be `sum(x.^2)`, which will square each element of the `x` vector and then sum over all squared elements.

Comment: The term you want here is "transpose" rather than "invert".